# Adding image to ListView from database

Tags: android, database, image, listview

How can i add image to `ListView`?

I put images in assets folder and the name of the image in **database** table.

```
class Aray extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public Aray() {
        super(ChapterList.this, R.layout.chapterlist, chapName);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = in.inflate(R.layout.chpter_row, parent, false);

        TextView cName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chap_name_row);
        TextView sCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chap_count_row);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivrow);
        iv.???

        cName.setText(chapName[position]);
        sCount.setText(storyCount[position]);

        return (row);
    }

}
```

something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7

    };
```

Pass the ids through adapter:

```
 CustomList adapter = new
                    CustomList(MainActivity.this, data, imageId);
```

Pass the resource ids of your images through the Adapter class's constructor and set to the `ImageView` like

`iv.setImageResource(imageId[position]);`

Refer [this tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)